# What does this awk command mean, exactly?

Tags: awk

Can you explain to me the meaning of this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while (getline < "list") list[$1]}; $1 in list'
```

Comment: Is there a specific part of it you don't understand?  Does `awk(1)` help at all?

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
awk 'BEGIN {while (getline < "list") list[$1]}; $1 in list' somefilename
```

which is the same as

```
awk 'BEGIN {while (getline < "list") array[$1]} $1 in array' somefilename
```

(in which I have only renamed the variable `list` to `array` and removed a redundant `;`) first reads from a file called `list` and will then read from `somefilename` (or standard input, if `somefilename` is not supplied) and only print out the lines from that file whose first column also exists in the first column of the `list` file.

Written in "long form", the `awk` script may be written as

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# This block runs before processing input data.
BEGIN {
    # Read "list" line by line.
    while (getline <"list")
        array[$1] = 1  # Make an entry in the associative array
                       # with the first column as key.
}

# This block processes data.
# If the first column of the data is a key in the array, print the whole line.
$1 in array { print }
```

In short, it's a primitive JOIN operation between two files on the first column of both files in which the files do not have to be sorted (it preserves the sorting order of `somefilename`). The result will be lines from `somefilename` whose first column matches one of the first columns in `list`.

Another way of doing it (almost) which does not preserve the order would be

```
join <( sort list ) <( sort somefilename )
```

Ordering of the result would be different and all columns of `list` would be part of the output (if one knows what column one would want, this may be fixed using the `-o` flag for `join`).

---

Changing `$1` in both places in the script to `$0` (the whole line rather than just the first column) will make the `awk` script equivalent to

```
grep -Fx -f list somefilename
```

Here, the `list` file is use by `grep` as a list of patterns (`-f list`) that will be used to do fixed string (`-F`), whole line (`-x`), comparisons in `somefilename`.  Matching lines from `somefilename` will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion probably comes from the overloading of the name `list`.  Perhaps this would make it more clear:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while( getline < "filename" ) myarray[$1] }'
```

This will populate the array `myarray` with the first field from each line of the file `filename`.

From `awk`'s manual:

> The 'function' [..] `getline <file` sets $0 to the next record from
>   `file`.